# Blank CD burnt but no file in it?

Tags: windows-xp, iso-image, compact-disc

I made a Bootable XP ISO to make some XP CD. When I write them to blank CD, it writes successfully (ie, no error reported) but after writting there was no file on the CD.

I tried 7 CDs and all failed.

I then used a re-writeble CD and it worked as desired.

Now what is the cause? How can I write that XP ISO in blank CD and not in re-writable CD?

Comment: are you sure your ISO is not corrupted? Check md5 for original and yours. After you might try to redownload iso

Comment: It sounds like you have a bad batch of CD's - can you confirm you burn other data to CD or if the issue is only either with ISO or with the disc!

Comment: Thank you Mr.Dave for correcting my mistakes and for your replay.I burnt only ISO files not data files.and my ISO is OK,cause i burnt this ISO in my re-writable CD.And is it possible that all 7 CDs have bad batch?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Get a new batch of good quality discs and burn at the slowest speed possible.